# How to write SQL query to pick one record from two table which are having different column values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following 2 tables TableA and TableB need to find the difference and get the result from TableA if there is any changes in any of the Cost columns. Ignore the same records from TableA and TableB I have tried with EXCEPT which is yielding the wrong result.

TABLEA

| JobNo | Brand | Cost1 | Cost2 | Cost3 | Cost4 | Cost5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 175196 | Vintage | 216347 | 217429 | 218516 | 219609 | 220707 |
| 200330 | Vintage | 427169 | 429305 | 431451 | 433608 | 435776 |
| 211746 | Modern | 285621 | 287049 | 288484 | 289927 | 291376 |

TABLEB

| JobNo | Brand | Cost1 | Cost2 | Cost3 | Cost4 | Cost5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 175196 | Vintage | 227030 | 228165 | 229306 | 230453 | 231605 |
| 200330 | Vintage | 444551 | 446774 | 449007 | 451252 | 453509 |
| 211746 | Modern | 285621 | 287049 | 288484 | 289927 | 291376 |

Result Expected

| JobNo | Brand | Cost1 | Cost2 | Cost3 | Cost4 | Cost5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 175196 | Vintage | 216347 | 217429 | 218516 | 219609 | 220707 |
| 200330 | Vintage | 427169 | 429305 | 431451 | 433608 | 435776 |

```
SELECT JobNo,Brand,Cost1,Cost2,Cost3,Cost4,Cost5 FROM TableA(NOLOCK)
EXCEPT
SELECT JobNo,Brand,Cost1,Cost2,Cost3,Cost4,Cost5 FROM TableB(NOLOCK)
```

Comment: What are you getting when you run this `EXCEPT` statement? Given your sample data, it should spit out your desired results.

Comment: You might want to read this before you continue splattering NOLOCK hints all over the place. https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

Comment: Here's a working example using your data (or most of your data) as well as your SQL: https://dbfiddle.uk/jBmgFV6N

Answer (score -1):

> find the differences between TableA and TableB based on the Cost columns and retrieve the results from TableA if there are any changes

You can use this:

```sql
SELECT JobNo, Brand, Cost1, Cost2, Cost3, Cost4, Cost5
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM TableA

  EXCEPT

  SELECT *
  FROM TableB
) AS diff;
```

[image]

Comment: I edited my first answer thanks for point out my falut.

You can use this 

SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM A

  EXCEPT

  SELECT *
  FROM B
) AS diff;

Comment: You should post a link to the fiddle instead of a screenshot. We don't like screenshots of text or code here.

Answer (score -1):

The EXCEPT is right, you can see it here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f6fc2/2

[image]

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/11/nolock-is-bad-and-you-probably-shouldnt-use-it/

Comment: https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6072/sql-server-nolock-anomalies-issues-and-inconsistencies/?utm_source=AaronBertrand

Comment: https://sqlnuggets.com/nolock-may-not-be-doing-what-you-think/